# HtmlCleaner not processing character references

Tags: html, htmlcleaner

A project I'm working on is using a very old (2.1-gr12) version of [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) to get info out of HTML files. We found out that HtmlCleaner is not decoding character references such as `&amp;`, neither in HTML element text content, nor in HTML attribute values! For example the `test` attribute `<span test="foo&amp;bar">stuff &amp; more stuff</span>` would be interpreted as `foo&amp;bar`, and the content would be interpreted as `stuff &amp; more stuff`.

Does HtmlCleaner not support character references? Was this added in a later version, or is there some setting we need to set?

Comment: The original version of my question talked about attributes, but after more investigation it turns out `HtmlCleaner` apparently doesn't decode character references anywhere! :O